# Create a custom view group

Tags: android, android-custom-view, circular-list

I want to create a layout with number of childs in circular design and from centre of the view point i need to draw lines to every child.

Please find below image is childs in view are 4. [image]

Comment: You can request people here to write code for you... They don't work for you...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have posted my issue to get help form you all. But i have resolved it by creating custom views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this by Overriding the `drawchild` method of android gallery.

Check out [ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu) which may help you but you have to make some changes in this code according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks GrlsHu. I have created custom view show views like that.

Comment: Welcome.. :) Vote answer if it helped you